# How to change column name when we are using case ? SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, case

I am trying to get result in one row using case statement it is showing me correct result but in two rows let me show you my query,

```
select  
    v.Id,
    v.VisitNumber,
    v.EndTime as VisitEndTime,
    case when srh.ReviewerRole = 2 then srh.CreatedOn end as TeamLeaderApproval,
    case when srh.ReviewerRole = 4 then srh.CreatedOn end as ProgramManagerApproval
from
    visit v 
inner join 
    SurveyReviewHistory srh on v.Id = srh.VisitId 
where 
    v.Status = 5 
    and v.Id = 5957
```

it is showing me result in this format,

```
Id  VisitNumber VisitEndTime TeamLeaderApproval ProgramManagerApproval
5957 Visit_U_6   2019-05-26     2019-05-26             NULL
5957 Visit_U_6   2019-05-26     NULL                2019-05-26
```

I want to get result in one row if Reviewrole 2 then show createdon time in team leader column or if review role 4 then show createdon time in program manager column

Hopes for your suggestion

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use conditional aggregation:

```
select  v.Id,
        v.VisitNumber,
        v.EndTime as VisitEndTime,
        max(case when srh.ReviewerRole = 2 then srh.CreatedOn end) as TeamLeaderApproval,
        max(case when srh.ReviewerRole = 4 then srh.CreatedOn end) as ProgramManagerApproval
from  visit v 
inner join SurveyReviewHistory srh 
    on v.Id = srh.VisitId 
where v.Status = 5 
and v.Id = 5957
group by v.Id, v.VisitNumber, v.EndTime
```

The idea is quite simple - you group by all the columns that give identical results in the original query.
Then, you use `max` to get the value of the `case expression` because when you are using `max` between two values where one of these values is `null`, the other value will be the value that's selected by the `max` aggregation function.

Comment: yes its working but can you please explain max lines in query what thery are actually doing ?

Comment: Sure, I've added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT K.Id,
       K.VisitNumber,
       K.VisitEndTime,
       FIRST_VALUE(K.TeamLeaderApproval) OVER(PARTITION BY K.Id,K.VisitNumber, K.VisitEndTime ORDER BY K.TeamLeaderApproval DESC) AS TeamLeaderApproval,
       FIRST_VALUE(K.ProgramManagerApproval) OVER(PARTITION BY K.Id,K.VisitNumber, K.VisitEndTime ORDER BY K.ProgramManagerApproval DESC) AS ProgramManagerApproval
From  (
   select  
     v.Id,
     v.VisitNumber,
     v.EndTime as VisitEndTime,
     case when srh.ReviewerRole = 2 then srh.CreatedOn end as TeamLeaderApproval,
     case when srh.ReviewerRole = 4 then srh.CreatedOn end as ProgramManagerApproval
   from visit v 
      inner join 
          SurveyReviewHistory srh on v.Id = srh.VisitId 
    where 
       v.Status = 5 and v.Id = 5957
  ) as K
```

Comment: @Doc if my solution works, as you expected, please do not forget the UpVote and mark it as answer. Thank you

Comment: i tried your solution there are errors in this query

Comment: @Doc please share the error message, so that I can help you to resolve it

Comment: i edited your answer according to column of my table now its working fine. There is no condition for review role that will give desire result. Well, I am using zohar solution.

Comment: @Doc I have updated the query and now it contains the condition for  review.

Comment: @Doc As you are new to Stackoverflow, I need to say that, if you found the Zohar's answer the solution you are seeking, then you should mark it as answer, however you can Upvote any other answer's that are correct but not the one you are seeking.